# Calculate angle of scissors image

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I have a pair of black scissors (image below) and I want to calculate its angle. The angle is between 180 and 0.so I used `cv2.line()` to get two lines for angle calculation but I could only detect angel if its 180 or 0.how can I find a " > " shape with contours?(the handle is also black)

[image]

```
#Decapitary
import cv2
import numpy as np
import cv2.cv as cv
import math
import sys

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
max_area =0

while(1):

# Take each frame
_, frame = cap.read()

# Convert BGR to HSV

hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)


lower_black = np.array([0,0,0]) 
upper_black = np.array([180,255,30])
mask= cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red)

mask = cv2.GaussianBlur(mask,(1,1),2)
mask = cv2.dilate(mask, np.ones((7,7),np.uint8))      
mask = cv2.erode(mask, np.ones((5,5),np.uint8))        


edges = cv2.Canny(mask,thresh,thresh*5)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edges,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE) ### use this to calculte the angel.

   for c in contours:     
        area = cv2.contourArea(c)


        if area > max_area:
            max_area = area
            yu = c

        nss = np.asarray(yu,dtype=np.int32)
        cv2.polylines(frame, [nss], 0 , (0,0,250)) 


cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
cv2.imshow('edges',edges)
cv2.imshow('mask',mask)
k = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
if k == 27:
    break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Im open to ideas and really need help.just show me the right direction please

EDIT:

Can I train a cascade to find a specific point a an object(in this case 3points on edges to calculate angel) ???

Comment: What is the expected output? What is the actual output? Are you processing each scissor image separately?

Comment: @msw input is me showing the scissor to webcam. output is suppose to be the two lines near the two edges of scissor like " > ". but the lines end in the handle

Comment: Is it always the same pair of scissors? If so, just trimming the image to its minimum width with no white edge pixels will tell you the distance between the finger holes and would allow you to use a lookup table for the angle.

Comment: @MarkSetchell yes its the same pair but the frame is from webcam feed(noisy background and the size is different everytime 'cuz distance to cam is changing).I need to calculate angel in every possible way

Comment: You could maybe use a Hough transform to find the centroids of the two finger-holes and calculate the distance between them. Then knowing the radius of the holes in the image and the radius in the actual object, you could scale to find the distance between the holes which would give you the angle.

Comment: @MarkSetchell so clever thank you but my fingers are in fingerHoles so its difficult to detect with Hough transfrom(so many negative results ).